# Angular clear browser cache

Tags: .net, angular, angular8

After publishing a new version of my angular app I often see the old cached version until I hit Ctrl+F5 to clear it.
To avoid that I have a version number in the angular app matching the .net core api project version.
In the login page I call the api to get the version and if there is a mismatch I trigger window.reload(true).
Is this approach alright or is there a better/simpler way?

Comment: `location.reload(true)` XD

Answer (score 1):

In `angular.json` there is the `configurations` section which contains the `production` configuration. Here you can set `outputHashing` to value `all` and if you call `ng build --prod` the built file names will contain their hash in he `dist` folder. If the content of the file changes after a version update, the hash will be different it follows it will be downloaded.

An example:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true
  }
}
```

Documentation about the referred build parameters can be found [here](https://angular.io/cli/build).

However it is possible that the `index.html` itself will be cached (its file name is not hashed) and the content with the new hashes won't be downloaded because the browser uses the cached `index.html` with the cached angular contents. In this case the `index.html` should be served by the .NET backend with `no-cache`,  `no-store` http header properties. Details about cache control [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

Comment: Apparently the "outputHashing": "all" was the default in angular.json.
Hence, I've also added the below block to the .Net core api
`app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                {
                    context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
                    context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
                }
            });`

Comment: Apparently yes. I didn't encountered that situation since then